# How to match 2 key value pairs in unstructured string that looks like column

Tags: ruby, logstash

I have a document with some lines like:

```
  Example requested: 24:00:00            Example Used: 01:14:11
```

What I want is to have is:

```
{
"example_requested": "24:00:00",
"example_used": 01:14:11
}
```

What I tried (this is `ruby` block):

```
if x =~ /(Example requested)/
        example_requested = x.scan(/^(?:.*?: ){1}(.*)$/)[0]
        example_requested = (memory_requested * "").gsub(/\s+/, "")
```

I get

```
"example_requested" : "24:00:00ExampleUsed:01:14:11"
```

Tried out some combinations in https://rubular.com/r/WOmAqx4YkOnDER but this code does not actually work like here when I put it in `ruby code` block in `Logstash`. Only thing that actually works here is to skip empty spaces with `gsub`. Any help is appreciated

**UPDATE**:

```
if x =~ /(Example Requested)/
        example_used = x.scan(/^(?:.*?: ){2}(.*)$/)[0]
        example_used = (example_used * "").gsub(/\s+/, "")
```

actually results with:

```
"example_used": 01:14:11
```

but I guess there's a better way to do it

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this myself, but I'm pretty sure that `kv` filter could be the way to go here. It accepts `field_split_pattern` which can be some regex of multiple white spaces and `value_split_pattern` which can be `" :"`.

Documentation of [`kv`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-kv.html) filter.

Comment: Answers are intended to be definitive. "I'm pretty sure" may qualify this as a comment at best.

Answer (score 1):

```
str = "Example requested: 24:00:00            Example Used: 01:14:11"
```

```
r = /\p{Alpha}[\p{Alpha} ]*|\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}/    
Hash[*str.scan(r)]
  #=> {"Example requested"=>"24:00:00", "Example Used"=>"01:14:11"}
```

Note:

```
str.scan(r)
  #=> ["Example requested", "24:00:00", "Example Used", "01:14:11"]
```

The regular expression reads, "match a Unicode letter (`\p{Alpha}`) followed by zero or more (`*`) Unicode letters or spaces, or three pairs of digits (`\d{2}`) separated by colons". See [Hash::[]](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this worked fine:

```
ruby {
        code => '
            message = event.get("message")
            matches = message.scan(/\s*([a-zA-Z ]+):\s+(([\d:.BKMGT]+))/)
            matches.each { |x|
                event.set(x[0].downcase.gsub(/ /, "_"), x[1])
            }
        '
    }
```